# Should I publish a series of children's books simultaneously or separately?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, publisher, children

I have written a picture text book for children and there will be around 20 books in the series. I have a publisher that has shown interest, and wants to know whether I want my books to be published as a collection in one volume of work, or for all books to be published separately but at the same time, or for all books to be considered distinctly on their individual merits, potentially allowing time for the first to generate sales. I am new to this so it would be great for someone to give a little advice.

Comment: How long are they? What age group are they aimed at? Why would you publish them as one volume? Do you need the money from the first one to produce the second  one? Too many questions.

Comment: They are roughly 8 pages long each book, with lots of pictures. I don't know why I would publish them in volume, I don't even know what they mean by that! And what do they mean by publishing them separately but at the same time? I thought they would be the ones to decide that, not me? I'm so confused

Comment: And sorry, they are for age group 1yr - 4 yr

Comment: This almost sounds like you might not be talking about a publisher but a vanity publisher that is planning on charging you for the service of printing your book.  If that's the case, then it's likely you're being scammed if they're telling you that they're an actual real publisher. Authors don't pay real publishers... Publishers pay authors.

Answer (score 1):

If I think about all the picture books my son has owned, the only ones (that I can think of) that are less than twenty pages are the very cheap, cardboard-page books that we bought from the supermarket for a pound each.

Everything else has many pages.

You really have to talk to the publisher.

Publishing in a volume just means putting more than one story in a single book.